# is there any way to get to velocity of a fluid and use it in the cycle material editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, scripting, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to use flip fluids to make lava is there any way to use the motion blur vectors, or get the velocity to mix a material. or in the script editor is there anyway to drive that.